# mongo query for equivalent SQL query ( GROUPBY COUNT DISTINCT )

Tags: mongodb

My mongo collection has documents with the following keys [ A, B, C ]

My SQL query would look like this.

```
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT B) from table where C == 'some_value' GROUP BY A;
```

What would an efficient way to do the same in Mongo ? I am trying to see if there is a way to do this using aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation framework.  But should we assume that your documents are flat - i.e. {A:x, B:y, C:z} or something like that?

```
db.collection.aggregate( {$match:{C:z}},
         {$group:{_id:"$A",
                  Bs :{$addToSet:"$B"}
         },
         {$unwind:"$Bs"},
         {$group:{_id:"$_id",
                  distinctBcount: {$sum:1}
         }
);
```